# Error while connecting to Oracle DB on server

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, toad, ora-12514

I am getting an error while trying to connect to oracle DB on the server throught Toad.  The error message is :
ORA-12514: TNS:listener could not resolve Service_Name given in connect descriptor.
Everything was working fine till yesterday but today my server got restarted and i am not ablt to connect to DB. I tried tnsping as well and it is working fine:

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-NOV-20
10 15:13:29

Copyright (c) 1997 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
c:\oracle\ora92\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
 (HOST = MY4D) (PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME =sim)))
OK (80 msec)

I did **lsnrctl start** and it says Service OracleOraHome92TNSListener already running.

Still oracle throught toad is not working. Can anyone help me in solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens when your oracle services are not running. You will see the services by names "Oracle..TNSListener" and another service with name "OracleServicesim" in your services.msc. Check if both of them are running, or restart both those services. Then try to connect. It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Restarting second service (OracleServicesim)helped.

Comment: Restarting service helped me only to make toad connection work. But when i execute my solution, it is still giving error   "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I have not touched web.config page ...so database entry is correct. It was working fine till server restarted today. Any other option/solution i have ?

Comment: @RMN - Your question was to resolve the connection issue in TOAD. Not the Object ref error in your app right? That seems to be some other issue in your app probably

Comment: Yeah you are correct. First the application stopped working then i broke issue into piece and found the toad not working. So can you help any in this. Any other service which can stop connection between asp.net application solution on your machine connecting to database on a server ?

Comment: @RMN - best way is to debug your app and see where or which line of code is throwing the error and check the null objects in your code.

Comment: For posterity, I encountered a similar problem connecting with sqlplus to an Oracle 8i server.  Whenever I used a TNS name to connect, it ignored me and used the hostname instead.  I discovered this by examining the packets and comparing to a working system.  The problem was the 'network/admin/sqlnet.ora' file:

 NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = sub.sample.com
 NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, ONAMES, HOSTNAME)

Despite the prominence of TNSNAMES adapter in the DIRECTORY_PATH, it was still using HOSTNAMES.  I just commented-out the NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN line, and it fixed the problem.